# Query dsl with predicate and fetch join

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

is there a chance to fetch join entity with using predicate?

```
    @Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String hobby;

    private String favouriteColor;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CLASS_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Classroom classroom;
}

@Entity
public class Classroom {

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String classRoom;

    private List<Student> students;

}
```

I have some predicate

```
public class StudentPredicate {

    private StudentPredicate() {}

    public static Predicate createPredicate(final Student filter) {
        QStudent student = QStudent.student;

        BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();

        if (isNotBlank(filter.getHobby())) {
            builder.and(student.hobby.eq(filter.getHobby());
        }
        if (isNotBlank(filter.getFavouriteColor())) {
            builder.and(student.favouriteColor.eq(filter.getFavouriteColor()));
        }


        return builder.getValue();
    }

}
```

and repository

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Integer>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Student> {

}
```

and now how can I find all students with fetched classrooms?

```
studentRepository.findAll(predicate)
```

How to say to query dsl that these findAll should fetch classroom?

Answer (score 0):

As there's **FetchType.LAZY** for classroom field in Student class, so here while you call **getClassRoom()** will actually fetch the related entity from db or either you can use **FetchType.EAGER**.

Comment: yes, I know, but some other stuff need to use only Student without fetched ClassRoom. So I think if there is some possibility like "FETCH JOIN" for given query with Predicate